# Angular.js setting ng-options with in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to set the correct select option based on a value in the ng-repeat.

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/vok080z4/5/

Crazy, if you view the example, why is dave set to apples, but no one else is?

```
<body ng-app="eApp">
  <div ng-controller="splitsController" ng-cloak>

    <table class="widefat fixed" cellspacing="0">
      <thead class="thead">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Fruit</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="tbody">
        <tr ng-repeat="order in data.orders" ng-class-odd="'alternate'">
          <td>{{order.name}}</td>
          <td>
            <select ng-model="fruitSelect">
              <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
              <option ng-repeat="fruit in data.fruits track by fruit.id" value="{{fruit.id}}" ng-selected="fruit.id === order.fruitId">
                {{fruit.name}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </td>
         <td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want all of the dropdowns set to `apples` by default?

Comment: No, they should be set to whatever they ordered. Notice the fruitId in the orders array.

Comment: @satpal YES that's it!

Comment: @Satpal, you changed id to fruitId in the fruits array. Is that necessary?

Comment: @Satpal, that's pretty lame because one is a primary key and one is a foreign key and they may never be named the same thing is real life cases...

Comment: @Satpal, I think that's better, but I don't think it's unreasonable to have what I had too. Sometimes you only get to consume services and you can't control the DTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to generate select options and more important use [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to persist the selected value.

```
<select ng-model="order.fruitId" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in data.fruits">
      <option value="">-- Select One --</option>              
</select>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/30qn56gq/1/)